# Using a variable in a file with extern keyword which is defined as static as well as global in the base file?

Tags: c, static, extern, storage-class-specifier

Can we use a variable in a file using extern which is defined as both static as well as global in the base file?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can't `extern`-redefine a `static` variable, though you can `extern`-redeclare it.

WRONG:

```
 //filescope
 static int x = 42;
 extern int x = 43; //WRONG
```

CORRECT:

```
 //filescope
 static int x = 42;
 extern int x; //redeclares the previous STATIC x (no linkage)
```

`extern` doesn't declare a linkage-having identifier with external linkage: it (re)declares the identifier with its **previous** linkage (**external** or **internal**) unless there was no such previous declaration or the declaration didn't have linkage (non-static locals have no linkage).

[6.2.2p4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p4:):

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in
> a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible,31)
> if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the
> linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the
> linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is
> visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the
> identifier has external linkage.

I wouldn't try to push this behavior with complex overshadowing, though, because neither gcc and clang like extern-redeclarations of an inner static and if you have intervening auto variables between a global static and an innermost `extern` redeclaration, then the innermost identifier will have conflicting linkage, which results in undefined behavior as per [6.2.2p7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p7) (Thanks to [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) for pointing this out).

accepted by gcc and clang:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int x = 42;
extern int x;
int main()
{
    extern int x;
    printf("x=%d\n", x); //42
}
```

accepted by clang only (technically UB due to conflicting linkage)

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int x = 42;
extern int x;
int main()
{
    int x = 1000;
    printf("x=%d\n", x); //1000
    {
        extern int x; //conflicting (external) linkage
        //=> undefined behavior due to http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p7
        printf("x=%d\n", x); //42 on clang; compile time error on gcc
    }
}
```

perhaps curiously unaccepted by either:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int x = 42;
extern int x;
int main()
{
    static int x = 1000;
    extern int x;
    printf("x=%d\n", x); //1000?
    
}
```

Comment: For the example with `int x = 1000;` inside `main`, the standard is not ambiguous, and both GCC and Clang are conforming: at the inner `extern int x;`, only the `x` of `int x = 1000;` is visible, since it hides the prior declarations, and so it is the one referred to by 6.2.2 4. The prior declaration, `int x = 1000;` has no linkage, so the new `x` has external linkage. Then `x` has been declared with both internal linkage (by the first `static int x = 42` and external (by this new one), for which the standard says the behavior is not defined, so both GCC and Clang conform, since anything does.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for explaining. This UB due to conflicting language is disappointing, though. Yet another instance of UB doesn't buy any speed and is perfectly preventable at compile time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. I've edited your info into the answer.